# Is there a 3D Hebrew Alphabet?

Tags: aleph-bet-letters, see-sight-vision-blind, hearing

Is there a 3D Alef-Bet? In which case Samekh could be something like a sphere, etc.

Or for that matter something 4D like [kinetic sculptures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hO7oyAOk9U0), which would explain how the aseret ha-dibrot were legible from every direction . . .

Could this be related to the [form of the actual sound waves in the air](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsjV1gjBMbQ) when the letters are pronounced? In which case people would literally be seeing the physical forms of the sounds, explaining the synesthesia as well?

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: The aleph (gematria=1) might be considered a symbol representing simple, unrestricted, infinite oneness/simplicity. Projected into 2 dimensions, that might correspond to 2D axes.  So in 3D it might be depicted as 3D axes.  (But, if that's true, that ability to be depicted in n dimensions might be unique to the aleph in its transcending limitation.)

Comment: The Maharal often considers the symbolism of numbers in terms of geometry.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that @Loewian. Source?

Comment: @robev how could this be off-topic?

Comment: @robev I don't think it's off-topic. Just a poorly justified question.

Comment: Throughout his works.

Comment: A good Q, but very ill-phrased. Maybe start with the background, I assume you're trying to visualize Matan Torah where people supposedly saw the spoken letters. Anyway I think the answer is a sound NO, there's no translation of the letters into the third dimension. The only this we know is that the letters on the Tablets were chiseled through, but that does not make them 3D.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with the question . . .

Comment: By source I meant example @Loewian.

Comment: @al then what Is. 3d?

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially impossible to prove that nobody has ever proposed the existence such a 3-dimensional alphabet, but I have never heard of such a thing and I think it's safe to say that no major religious scholars have ever proposed that such a thing exists.

Comment: Some of Yitzchak Ginsburgh's work seems to indicate that it might exist.

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull so why don't you write an answer with some details about that.

Comment: I don't have an answer, just speculation based on some of what I've read. @Daniel

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull in that case, if you added that context to the question, it would make the question much better IMO. Right now it's completely unclear why you'd even ask the question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There are many 3-D Aleph Bets. One is available for free download [here.](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/kCT9oCChRQH-hebrew-letters-by-using3d) It should be compatible with most 3-D printers.

Comment: Given the OP’s example of a samech being a sphere I’m not sure this is quite what he had in mind. Though, question’s not worded too well, so maybe it is.

Comment: @Doniel given the way the question was worded I think this is the best answer possible